# How to arrange table rows up and down along auto arranging row number sequentially?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

HTML:

```
<table class="myTable" border="1" width="80%">
  <tr >
    <td></td>
    <td>one</td>
    <td><button onClick="MoveUp();">&#8679;</button></td>
    <td><button onClick="MoveDown();">&#8681;</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>two</td> 
    <td><button onClick="MoveUp();">&#8679;</button></td>
    <td><button onClick="MoveDown();">&#8681;</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>three</td> 
    <td><button onClick="MoveUp();">&#8679;</button></td>
    <td><button onClick="MoveDown();">&#8681;</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>four</td> 
    <td><button onClick="MoveUp();">&#8679;</button></td>
    <td><button onClick="MoveDown();">&#8681;</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>five</td> 
    <td><button onClick="MoveUp();">&#8679;</button></td>
    <td><button onClick="MoveDown();">&#8681;</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
 table.myTable {
     counter-reset: rowNumber;
 }

 table.myTable tr {
     counter-increment: rowNumber;
 }

 table.myTable tr td:first-child::before {
     content: counter(rowNumber);
     min-width: 1em;
     margin-right: 0.5em;
 }
```

JavaScript:

```
 function MoveUp() {
     var tablebody = document.getElementById('mytable'); 
     if(TableLocation > 0) { 
         tablebody.moveRow(TableLocation, TableLocation - 1);
         TableLocation = TableLocation - 1;
     }
 }

 function MoveDown() {
     var tablebody = document.getElementById('mytable'); 
     if((TableLocation > 0) && (TableLocation < tablebody.rows.length - 1)) { 
         tablebody.moveRow(TableLocation, TableLocation + 1);
         TableLocation = TableLocation + 1;
     }
 }
```

I am getting table data from back end and adding row number from css. I am using JavaScript for moving the rows up and down. It is not working. If Moving rows up and down is happened it has to auto arrange the row number from one to last.

Here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tejdeep/z5hroz4p/7/).

Comment: Something like [dataTables](http://www.datatables.net/examples/index) does exactly what you want!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Working version**](http://jsfiddle.net/z5hroz4p/8/)

You have to find the parent `tr` of the button and then find the element to wich append before. Because of there is no function for append after one element you have to find the second next element when you want to move down.

Move up function:

```
function MoveUp() {
    var table,
        row = this.parentNode;

    // find the parent tr ( the row element )
    while ( row != null ) {
        if ( row.nodeName == 'TR' ) {
            break;
        }
        row = row.parentNode;
    }
    // the parent of the row is the table body
    table = row.parentNode;
    // insert the row before it's previevs siblings
    table.insertBefore ( row, get_previoussibling( row ) );
}
```

Move down function:

```
function MoveDown() {
    var table,
        row = this.parentNode;

    while ( row != null ) {
        if ( row.nodeName == 'TR' ) {
            break;
        }
        row = row.parentNode;
    }
    table = row.parentNode;
    // you have to find the second next siblings to append before
    // NOTE: if the second parameter of the 'insertBefore' function is null
    //       it will append the row to the table! 
    table.insertBefore ( row, get_nextsibling ( get_nextsibling( row ) ) );
}
```

Comment: Hi, @TheGr8_Nik. If I have 5 columns and out of that I have one column which I don't want to change while moving up or down. So how can that be possible with this code?